# Fill a word document with inputs taken from Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

I need to fill an Bank Account Form Word Document, from inputs taken from an Windows Form Application. I've searched the web about it, and found about `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` that can be used to edit a Word Document. However I'm not sure how I can put textboxes in the doc and put the information.

I'm attaching a picture of the form. Please give me any suggestions/help about it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various approaches. Which to use depends to a certain extent on what kind of additional editing the user may want / need / is allowed to perform before the document is saved / printed. Here's a list of possibilities that come to mind:

1. Form fields (when the document should be protected against changes)
2. Content controls (can also be protected, but also allow formatted input)
3. Bookmarks (simplest for the "interop")
4. "Find/Replace" (Russel's suggestion - not my personal preference)
5. Mail merge (although less with input directly into a Form)

If there should be no user interaction you should also look at generating the file using the Open XML file format, especially if a server environment is involved.

Follow-up from Comments: Content controls are accessed using the `Document.SelectContentControlsByTitle` and/or `.SelectContentControlsByTag` methods. These return an array of content controls with the specified Title / Tag property passed as an argument. Unlike bookmarks, multiple content controls can have the same title/tag. (This is why I say bookmarks are "simpler".)

Content Controls also have an ID property (long-ish number) that can be passed as a *string* as the Index parameter for the ContentControls collection. The ID is assigned by Word when the Content control is inserted into the document and is read-only. Assuming you'd create the document and thus could know the ID values for each content control, you could use this instead of the above methods. contentControl = Document.ContentControls("2087486648")

Comment: Thanks @Cindy... I'm already working using Find-Replace... But I'll look into Bookmarks and Content Controls... If possible, can you provide me any guide regarding these?

Comment: Could you please be more explicit about the "guidance" you'd like?

Comment: I mean any how to access a content control by interop...

Comment: added to the Answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is I create a Word document with some custom text in each box. For the Father's Name box, I'll put in {FathersName}. Then, when I open the document using the Word Interop, I perform search and replaces for each field to replace it with the data I want in that box. If a box is supposed to be empty, I replace it with "". To get the syntax for the replace command, record a macro in Word of you replacing something. Then, edit the macro.

Comment: Thanks buddy... I'll work on it, and if I stuck, I'll let you know... Thanks again